# Answering two people saying Kaddish out of sync

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish, amen

Suppose you have two people saying Kaddish and they come up the part when the congregation has to say Amen, but the two people aren't in sync.

Should you:
a) Say Amen to both;
b) Say Amen to the person who reaches that part first;
c) Say Amen to the person closest to you;
d) Do something else?

As always, please cite your sources.